# Change object via function parameter

Tags: javascript, function, object, parameters

Please, could you help me to figure out my problem.
I'm trying to return changed object via function parameter but it does not work for me as I expect.
I'm using Node.js version 13.8.0 under Windows 10 Professional Edition.

Below is a code snippet that I'm struggling with:

```
function a(x)
{
    var r = { v1: 0.0, v2: 0.0};
    r.v1 = 2.0 * x;
    r.v2 = x * x;
    return r;
}

function b(x, r)
{
    r = a(x);
}

var rr = { v1: 100.0, v2: 1000.0 };
b(5.0, rr);

console.log(rr);
```

At the end I expect that console.log(rr) will print out "{ v1: 10.0, v2: 25.0 }" but instead I have the "{ v1: 100.0, v2: 1000.0 }".

ESLint shows one error that does not seems to me important.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6otN0.jpg)
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for your issue.

```js
function a(x)
{
    var r = { v1: 0.0, v2: 0.0};
    r.v1 = 2.0 * x;
    r.v2 = x * x;
    return r;
}

function b(x, r)
{
    let changedObj = a(x);
    r.v1 = changedObj.v1;
    r.v2 = changedObj.v2;
    
}

var rr = { v1: 100.0, v2: 1000.0 };
b(5.0, rr);

console.log(rr);
```

Comment: That's not that I'm looking for. I understand that I can *return* updated object but I NEED TO RETURN IT VIA FUNCTION PARAMETER. (Just in case if there will be two, three or more objects to return.)

Comment: @LiehTzu Would you please check now?